# PHP won't check to see if a variable matches a part of a mysql row

Tags: php, mysql

```
 <?php
include "config.php";
?>

<?php 
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
?>

<?php

    $sql = "SELECT username FROM usr";
    $resultuser = $conn->query($sql); 
    $conn->close();



    $sql = "SELECT password FROM usr";
    $resultpass = $conn->query($sql);
    $conn->close();

?>

<?php
if ($resultuser == $username) {
    if($resultpass == $password) {
        echo "test";
    } else {
        echo "Wrong user or pass"   ;
    }
}


?>
```

Php won't send a query to mysql to check if the variable (username, and password) matches one of the rows in my mysql database.
I'm not sure what else to do
also config.php is the file which contains the code to connect to my mysql server.

Comment: why select them 1by1 when you can select username and password in 1 query?

Comment: $sql = "SELECT username FROM usr"; will output all user .. u've to specify with your select statement

Comment: You really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security.

Comment: Whatever DB library you are using (you don't say) you're probably using it wrong. What kind of library would return an scalar for a random query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to iterate over the obtained result as

```
 $result = $conn->query($sql);
 $resultUser= "";
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $resultUser =$row['username ']; 
    }
 }
```

and you are doing it wrong. In order to check where the username and password match the database entry should be like :

```
select * from user_table 
where username = 'pass_the_user_name' and password='user_password';
```

If this returns a row, that means this is a valid user else invalid credentials or anything.

Comment: This was from a long time ago, it did work but I have completely redesigned what I was using it for and changed lots.